# Replace Nan values with the minimum value in the same parent class

Tags: pandas

```
country      count

Argentina     3
Argentina     4
Argentina    NaN
Wales         1
Wales         3
Wales        NaN
```

Nan values, I want to make a minimum of the values that share the same countries as the NaN value.

Output Should Be:

```
Argentina     3
Argentina     4
Argentina     3
Wales         1
Wales         3
Wales         1
```

I tried bfill method but didn't manage this.
Thank You For Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is using `map`, `groupby` and `fillna`

`map` allows you to match by an index, when you create a groupby object it defaults to creating an index, (`as_index=True`) so it's pretty simple to map it back to your main dataframe.

```
df['count']  = df['count'].fillna(
          df['country'].map(df.groupby('country')['count'].min()))



print(df)

     country  count
0  Argentina    3.0
1  Argentina    4.0
2  Argentina    3.0
3      Wales    1.0
4      Wales    3.0
5      Wales    1.0
```

a simplier method is to use `.transform` which applies groupby operations without modifying the index

```
df['count'] = df['count'].fillna(
               df.groupby('country')['count'].transform('min'))

     country  count
0  Argentina    3.0
1  Argentina    4.0
2  Argentina    3.0
3      Wales    1.0
4      Wales    3.0
5      Wales    1.0
```